# validate refresh token and access token using JWT

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, server, backend

let me explain my situation. I currently do not have any database. but i write a simple server.js file and i send my requests to it(i run server.js using `node server.js`). i want implement the user-login ability for my project. here is my server.js source code:

```
// Sample tokens for simplicity (use a library for real token generation)
const secretKey = 'yourSecretKey'; // Replace with a secure secret key
const accessTokenExpiration = '1h'; // Access token expiration time (e.g., 1 hour)
const refreshTokenExpiration = '7d'; // Refresh token expiration time (e.g., 7 days)




// Sample user data for authentication      =================================================
const users = [
  { id: 1, username: 'test@gmail.com', password: '123456' },
  // Add more users as needed
];

// Sample tokens for simplicity (use a library for real token generation)
const accessToken = 'sampleAccessToken';
const refreshToken = 'sampleRefreshToken';

// Endpoint for user authentication

app.post('/auth/token', (req, res) => {
  const { grant_type, client_id, client_secret, username, password, refresh_token } = req.body;

  // Validate client_id and client_secret if needed

  // Check if grant_type is 'password' for user login
  if (grant_type === 'password') {
    // Find the user based on the provided username and password
    const user = users.find(u => u.username === username && u.password === password);

    if (user) {
      // Generate access token
      const accessToken = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id, username: user.username }, secretKey, { expiresIn: accessTokenExpiration });

      // Generate refresh token
      const refreshToken = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id, username: user.username }, secretKey, { expiresIn: refreshTokenExpiration });

      // Return tokens if user is found
      res.json({
        token_type: 'Bearer',
        expires_in: accessTokenExpiration,
        access_token: accessToken,
        refresh_token: refreshToken,
      });
    } else {
      // Return an error if user is not found
      res.status(404).json({ error: 'Invalid credentials' });
    }
  } else if (grant_type === 'refresh_token') {
    // Check if the provided refresh token is valid (use your logic for validation)
    // For simplicity, let's assume all refresh tokens are valid

    // Generate new access token
    const newAccessToken = jwt.sign({ /* Include relevant user information */ }, secretKey, { expiresIn: accessTokenExpiration });

    // Generate new refresh token
    const newRefreshToken = jwt.sign({ /* Include relevant user information */ }, secretKey, { expiresIn: refreshTokenExpiration });

    // Return new tokens
    res.json({
      token_type: 'Bearer',
      expires_in: accessTokenExpiration,
      access_token: newAccessToken,
      refresh_token: newRefreshToken,
    });
  } else {
    // Return an error for unsupported grant_type
    res.status(400).json({ error: 'Unsupported grant_type' });
  }
});





// Sample user data for registration
const registeredUsers = [];

// Endpoint for user registration
app.post('/user/register', (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  // Check if the email is already registered
  const existingUser = registeredUsers.find(u => u.email === email);
  if (existingUser) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Email already registered' });
  }

  // Register the new user
  const newUser = { id: registeredUsers.length + 1, email, password };
  registeredUsers.push(newUser);

  // You might want to generate an access token for the registered user here

  // Return a success message
  res.json({ message: 'User registered successfully', user: newUser });
});




// Start the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

As you can see, I don't have the secretKey. I also defined a client_secret in the application, which I don't know exactly where to get it from :)... anyway... this is not very important.

with this server.js i can login a user and receive a access_token and refresh_token. but i don't know how to validate it and renew the refresh token and access token. I want when the previous access token expires, the user will receive a new refresh token and a new access token using the previous refresh token. i read some documentations about JWT and validation methods. but i can't implement the right logic for doing this.
my main problem with this part of the code :

```
else if (grant_type === 'refresh_token') {
    // Check if the provided refresh token is valid (use your logic for validation)
    // For simplicity, let's assume all refresh tokens are valid

    // Generate new access token
    const newAccessToken = jwt.sign({ /* Include relevant user information */ }, secretKey, { expiresIn: accessTokenExpiration });

    // Generate new refresh token
    const newRefreshToken = jwt.sign({ /* Include relevant user information */ }, secretKey, { expiresIn: refreshTokenExpiration });

    // Return new tokens
    res.json({
      token_type: 'Bearer',
      expires_in: accessTokenExpiration,
      access_token: newAccessToken,
      refresh_token: newRefreshToken,
    });
  } else {
    // Return an error for unsupported grant_type
    res.status(400).json({ error: 'Unsupported grant_type' });
  }
});
```

i don't know the right logic for validating and also `Include relevant user information`. help me please :)!!!... And if you know anything else about this process, tell me please. Thanks!

also i using postman for testing my request and response. i send this HTTP POST request:
[postman test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQXst.png)

[{"key":"grant_type","value":"refresh_token","type":"text","equals":true},{"key":"refresh_token","value":"previous refresh_token which is receive from the login response.","type":"text","equals":true},{"key":"client_id","value":"2","type":"text","equals":true},{"key":"client_secret","value":"[ a hash code ]","type":"text","equals":true}].

and i got this with status code(400) :

```
{
    "error": "Unsupported grant_type"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You receive the 400 HTTP status code (Bad request) due to the fact that your server cannot understand the incoming JSON data (It's a bad request.), as you didn't parse this data in your Node.js code.**

**You should use the middleware functions of the body-parser and express modules in order to parse JSON data coming from the HTTP request:**

> npm i express
> npm i body-parser

or

> npm install express
> npm install body-parser

After that, add two middleware functions to the top of your code just like the following example code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const secret = "yourSecretKey";

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });

app.post("/generate-token", (req, res) => {
   const userId = req.body.user_id;
   jwt.sign({ user_id: userId }, secret, { expiresIn: "1h" }, (err, token) => {
      if (!err && token) {
         res.status(200).json({ token: token });
      }
   });
});

app.post("/verify-token", (req, res) => {
   const token = req.body.token;
   jwt.verify(token, secret, (err, user) => {
      if (!err && user) {
         res.status(200).json({ token: token, user: user });
      }
   });
});

const PORT = 3000;

app.listen(PORT, "127.0.0.1", () => {
   console.log(`Server running on ${PORT}.`);
});
```

Comment: i want send the request to this endpoint: auth/token. if grant_type === password generate a refresh token and access token . and if grant_type === refresh_token validate the refresh token and generate a new access token and refresh token.